# How can I wrap a v-switch with a v-tooltip with Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I attempted doing this like in the documentation
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/

```
<v-tooltip color="black" bottom >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-switch
            v-model="boo"
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            inset
          >
          </v-switch>
        </template>
        <div>
          Tooltip
        </div>
      </v-tooltip>
```

here :
https://codepen.io/julienreszka/pen/BazvmYN
But the tooltip isn't displayed and the css is wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

not really sexy, but you can wrap your switch in a div

```
<div 
  v-on="on"
  v-bind="attrs">
    <v-switch
      v-model="boo"
    ></v-switch>
</div>
```

Comment: just add style="width:min-content;" to the div and it will be perfect
https://codepen.io/julienreszka/pen/GRqPyNq

Answer (score -2):

`v-tooltip` is label of `v-switch`

```
<v-switch
  v-model="boo"
  inset>
  <template v-slot:label>
    <v-tooltip color="black" bottom>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <span
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on">switch label</span>
      </template>
      Tooltip
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>
</v-switch>
```

[switches document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/switches/#label)